# Python Celery Queues with seperated Servers(Docker Containers)

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, celery-task

I'm using Celery with RabbitMQ as a Broker. I have a publisher, which is a Flask server and two workers. They have each a different server(everything has it's own docker container. The App has 2 queues, each worker has it's own, and they should work on Tasks asynchronously. Everything seams to work fine, but when I look at the RabbitMQ Dashboard, every Task is pushed in one Queue. The two different queues are llama2-7b and llama2-13b. But each worker works just on it's own task.

Is this the right way to send a task? And what needs to change, so that the separate queues are used.

This is my publisher's config app.py:

```
simple_app = Celery('simple_worker',
broker='amqp://admin:mypass@rabbit:5672',
backend='rpc://')

CELERY_ROUTES = {
'core.tasks.llama2-7b': {'queue': 'llama2-7b'},
'core.tasks.llama2-13b': {'queue': 'llama2-13b'},
}
# send the task
if(content\['llm'\] == 'llama2-7b'):
r = simple_app.send_task('tasks.longtime_add', kwargs={'x': 1, 'y': 2},  queue='llama2-7b')
app.logger.info(r.backend)
return r.id
if(content\['llm'\] == 'llama2-13b'):
r = simple_app.send_task('tasks.longtime_add', kwargs={'x': 2, 'y': 2},  queue='llama2-13b')
app.logger.info(r.backend)
return r.id
```

One of two celery workers(different docker container):

```
app = Celery('llama2-13b', # Queue name
             broker='amqp://admin:mypass@rabbit:5672',
             backend='rpc://')

@shared_task() # Celery instance + queue
def longtime_add(x, y):
    logger.info('Got Request - Starting work ')
    print("LLama13b")
    time.sleep(4)
    logger.info('Work Finished ')
    return x + y
```

How the Worker gets started:

```
ENTRYPOINT celery -A tasks worker -Q llama2-13b,broadcast_tasks --loglevel=info
```

In RabbitMQ:

[image]

I am expecting, that both queues are used